# Error: pg_config executable not found. even though I have added the path to pg_config on environment variable

Tags: python, django, postgresql, saleor

I am trying to setup saleor (Django based). I did a "python -m pip install -r requirements.txt" as stated on the website. Things go well until the installation **Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.8.3** and then error is thrown. I have Postgre installed and I am on windows. I also have added the path to pg_config on my environment variable since it says **pg_config executable not found.** I am not sure how to proceed.

Here is the error that is shows up:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\ASPIRE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ASPIRE\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d7c359c_\\psycopg2-binary\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ASPIRE\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d7c359c_\\psycopg2-binary\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\ASPIRE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d7c359c_\psycopg2-binary\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\ASPIRE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d7c359c_\psycopg2-binary\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating C:\Users\ASPIRE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d7c359c_\psycopg2-binary\pip-egg-info\psycopg2_binary.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\ASPIRE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d7c359c_\psycopg2-binary\pip-egg-info\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\ASPIRE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d7c359c_\psycopg2-binary\pip-egg-info\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\ASPIRE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d7c359c_\psycopg2-binary\pip-egg-info\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\ASPIRE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d7c359c_\psycopg2-binary\pip-egg-info\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the environment variable [`PATH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/path) was not [set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1) properly. It is used to find executables that are not in the current directory.

For your purposes you don't have to change the `PATH` permanently:

- Open the command line (DOS box) with `cmd.exe`.
- Look at the current settings with `PATH`.
- Change the value for the current session with

  ```
  SET PATH="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin";%PATH%
  ```

Now it should work.

There is a way to set environment variables permanently on Windows, but they hide it better from version to version. A web search will usually help.

Comment: its a stupid question but, what do you mean by current settings with ```PATH``` ? Also, where do i change that value with ```PATH``` ?

Comment: @JackRogers I added some links and information.